# ajax replace with the new output from database

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am using ajax post and json in jquery to read the database output from php. now once i get the data onClick if I press the button again the data again gets populated below it. I want to replace the data with new content instead. I am a bit new to jquery & ajax. 
 The code i am using is:

```
    $.ajax({
type:'POST',
dataType: 'json',
url:'database.php',
data:{search: $("#search").val()},
success:function(rows){
    for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#output').html($('#output').html() + '<tr><td>'+ rows[i].Cat_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].Drug_Caty +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].G_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].B_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].D_Indications +'</td></tr>'        
        );
});
```

Comment: can you post your php code as well? So that we'll know what rows contains. And remove $('#output').html() since you replace the contents of that element everytime the loop is executed. You can use $.load instead.

Comment: I would output new data as html instead of json and simply: `success:function(html){
$('#output').html(html);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `empty()` method and then `append()` the new data, Try the following:

```
success:function(rows){
    $('#output').empty(); // Removes all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.
    for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#output').append('<tr><td>'+ rows[i].Cat_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].Drug_Caty +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].G_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].B_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].D_Indications +'</td></tr>'        
    };
}
```

Comment: "I want to replace the data with new content instead"

Comment: @sabithpocker and this replaces them.

Comment: Haa yes, i didnt notice the empty :)

Comment: I am having a table with title's below which all the database contents are displayed, so after having a empty() method my headings are erased and the data is placed in the table.

Comment: @user1456131 yes, empty will delete all the child nodes, if you want to preserve some elements you can use `not()` method before calling empty.

Comment: @user1456131 try the second code that posted in my answer before your for loop, that will preserve your headings, provided they are in the `<thead>`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
output.html = output.html + x;

doing it 3 times will produce

(((output.html + x) + y) + z)
```

May be what you are trying to do is

```
output.html = x;
```

If you want to replace only Ajax loaded contents and keep the other rows intact:

```
success:function(rows){
    if($('.ajaxloaded').length)$('.ajaxloaded').remove();
    for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#output').html('<tr class="ajaxloaded"><td>'+ rows[i].Cat_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].Drug_Caty +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].G_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].B_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].D_Indications +'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
```

also check @SangeethMenon suggesting a tbody if your #output is table

Comment: Suppose he has some data from page load in output and he don't want to remove it then what would he do

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `output` is the id of the `<tbody>` of a `<table>`

Then try this

```
$("#output").html("");

for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#output').html('<tr class="ajaxloaded"><td>'+ rows[i].Cat_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].Drug_Caty +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].G_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].B_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].D_Indications +'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
```

else if `output` the id of the `<table>` itself

Then try this

```
$("#output tbody").html("");


for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#output').html('<tr class="ajaxloaded"><td>'+ rows[i].Cat_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].Drug_Caty +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].G_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].B_Name +'</td><td>'+ rows[i].D_Indications +'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
```

P.S. To preserve the headings of the table you should put them inside the `<thead>` tags